# ConfigureAwait(false) и переключение контекста

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl

Есть серверное приложение, осуществляющее асинхронное взаимодействие с рядом внешних систем посредством использования TAP. Так как async/await стремится распространяться везде по коду, количество цепочек async-await достаточно велико. Вопрос заключается в том, как лучше поступать: использовать при каждом await ConfigureAwait(false) или же продолжать выполнение в том же потоке. То есть, по сути, как будет  более производительнее, брать любой свободный поток из пула для выполнения следующего вложенного await-а или же всю цепочку (например с уровнем вложенности равным 5) выполнять в рамках одного контекста. Насколько я понимаю, если не определять ConfigureAwait(false), то оставшаяся часть метода выполнится в том же потоке, но что, если этот поток сейчас занят? Будет ожидаться его освобождение? Что есть переключение контекста, это ожидание освобождения исходного потока или же перепрыгивания с одного потока на другой?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` используется в очень ограниченных случаях, не надо его использовать везде. Насчет скоростей - скорее всего разница будет минимальной или её вообще не будет.

Comment: По поводу его использования есть разные мнения. Кто-то говорит,что его надо использовать всегда, если контекст не важен. Кто-то же говорит обратное.  Меня этот вопрос интересует с точки зрения производительности, все-таки есть ощущение, что разница есть

Comment: _«то оставшаяся часть метода выполнится в том же потоке»_ это зависит от контекста вызывающего кода, если синхронизационный контекст отсутствует, значит нет никакого потока, куда можно «вернуться». Если что-то интересует с точки зрения производительности, это нужно измерять.

Comment: насколько я помню, то продолжение по умолчанию работает в захваченном контексте синхрнизации. А вы вроде про бекенд говорите - там у ваших потоков есть контекст? Есть что захватывать? Вот в UI приложениях основной UI поток облдает контекстом, потому там эта тема важна. А если вы не пишете библиотеку для UI, а просто пилите бекенд, то, скорее всего, что вы будете юзать configureAwait, что не будете - для вас ничего не изменится, так как ваши потоки подозреваю без контекста синхронизации живут.

Comment: Просто я обратил внимание на то, что потоки меняются. Приложение консольное, контекста синхронизации нет. То есть, насколько я понял, не важно, будет использоваться configureAwait или нет?

Comment: `То есть, насколько я понял, не важно, будет использоваться configureAwait или нет?` Да не важно.